# ssh: connect to host localmachine port 22: Network is unreachable Error

Tags: ssh, localhost, openstack

I'm home for the holidays and I'm trying to copy a file from my remote machine onto my local machine.

When I'm at work, I always use my remote machine off my work's connection. The only thing that's changed is that I'm obviously on a different network.

When I run `scp filename user@ip:/path/to/local/folder`

I get `ssh: connect to host localmachine port 22: Network is unreachable`

I've tried removing OpenSSH and re-installing it but it didn't work. I'm not sure what to do. I'm new to how computer systems work, so I'm not sure what's wrong :/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be localhost, not localmachine you connect to...? (Error says localmachine...)

Comment: Oh it could be! I'm sorry, I must be mixing them up. What I'm doing is going into the `Sharing` in `System Preferences` and using the `user@ip` under `Remote Login`. It probably is localhost! This is on a Mac.

Comment: So you obivously managed to log into remote machine to be able to execute the scp there, right? If that's the case you can just as well run (on your local machine) scp user@remoteip:/path/to/files/you/need /path/to/local/file and would not have to worry about what your current IP address is.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. What was causing the issue in the first place?

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Would you consider accepting / upvoting my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you obivously managed to log into remote machine to be able to execute the scp there, right? If that's the case you can just as well run (on your local machine) scp user@remoteip:/path/to/files/you/need /path/to/local/file and would not have to worry about what your current IP address is.

For the other direction to work your home computer would need to be accesible from outside. You could do a who on remote system to find out where you logged in from.